# I can't install any new npm packages on an expo project

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I have been working on a `react native` project and I used `expo-cli` for that. After I had a working alpha version, I generated an android version and published it.

Now I am back working on it, and I couldn't add any packages and I think somehow I made it worse, by removing `node_modules` and running the command `yarn install` I got this error : 
I couldn't post the stack trace because it is too long, but I created a gist containing the full stack trace : [link](https://gist.github.com/oflarcade/0cb48df9dd87814045e94d664a5c0059)

```
  yarn install                                
yarn install v1.15.2
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
info @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.9.3: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.9.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > @rhysforyou/react-native-carousel@0.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@>=16.6".
warning "expo > expo-background-fetch@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "expo-task-manager-interface@~1.0.0".
warning "expo > expo-google-sign-in@2.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-native@^0.55.4".
warning "expo > expo-location@2.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "expo-task-manager-interface@~1.0.0".
warning "expo > react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.11" has incorrect peer dependency "react@16.0.0-alpha.6".
warning "expo > react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.11" has incorrect peer dependency "react-native@^0.44.1".
warning "expo > expo-asset > url-loader@1.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning "firebase > @firebase/database@0.3.17" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/firestore@1.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/functions@0.4.3" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/messaging@0.3.16" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/storage@0.2.12" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/auth > @firebase/auth-types@0.5.5" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/auth > @firebase/auth-types@0.5.5" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/util@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/database > @firebase/database-types@0.3.8" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/firestore > @firebase/firestore-types@1.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/functions > @firebase/messaging-types@0.2.8" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/storage > @firebase/storage-types@0.2.8" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/storage > @firebase/storage-types@0.2.8" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/util@0.x".
warning " > react-native-maps@0.23.0" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.0 || ^16.0".
warning " > react-native-paper@2.15.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-vector-icons@*".
warning "react-native-paper > create-react-context@0.2.3" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.0.0".
warning "react-navigation > @react-navigation/native@3.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-gesture-handler@*".
warning "react-navigation > react-navigation-drawer@1.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-gesture-handler@^1.0.12".
warning "react-navigation > react-navigation-drawer@1.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha".
warning "react-navigation > react-navigation-stack@1.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-gesture-handler@^1.0.0".
warning "react-navigation > react-navigation-stack@1.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha".
warning "react-navigation > react-navigation-tabs@1.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha".
warning "react-navigation > @react-navigation/core > create-react-context@0.2.2" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.0.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[1/5] ⠂ fsevents
[2/5] ⠂ iltorb
[-/5] ⠂ waiting...
[4/5] ⠂ grpc
  ....
```

Comment: `yarn` is `yarn add` and `npm` is `npm install`

Comment: `yarn install` I used that after removing `node_modules`, I am quite aware of yarn add and npm install

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the gist, you would think it is `grp` problem... the actual problem was `node@12`.

After I downgraded to node 11, I got everything back to normal.

`(master) node -v  11.12`